# What am I supposed to do when people provide links only in their answers?

Tags: support, review-queues, first-answers

I came across an answer in the first answers review queue and I saw that it provided nothing more than 2 links in it which answers the question. What should I do with such answers? Flag them or let them be? I skipped that post because I didn’t know what to do.

Comment: Flag them as Not An Answer.